# Writing C pop function for a stack

Tags: c, pointers, stack

Hey I am writing a stack function and I am having trouble with popping values off the top of my stack. My push functions seems to be working though. This is the code for my push and pop.

```
void push(int num, int ** sp)
{
    if (++(*sp) == NULL)
        printf("Stack Overflow");
    else{
        printf("sp for push = %p \n", *sp);
        **sp++ = num;
    }
}
int pop(int **sp)
{
        printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);
        num = (**sp)--;
        printf("sp = %d\n",num);
        printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);

        return num;
 }
```

I was also having trouble checking for the null condition to prevent popping elements that are not even on the stack, but one problem at a time.

Anyway, the output of the function looks like this when I push 15 then 5

```
sp for push = 0x1761014 
sp for push = 0x1761018 
sp for pop = 0x1761018
sp = 5
sp for pop = 0x1761018
5
```

Where sp is the stack pointer. Notice how the stack pointer increments by the sizeof int. I am passing both pointers by reference, so they should both change the position in memory they are pointing too, but for the pop function when I am post-decrementing the pointer the value is not changing for some reason. Can someone help explain this to me? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your dereference operators `*`.

Comment: You have at least three different ways of incrementing/decrementing in this code.  They can't *all* be correct.  You should do some basic debugging to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Yeah thanks Joachim, I figured it out. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Any reason you use `**`, as you apparently use an array approach for the stack? The interfaces look very suspective.

Answer (score 0):

Basic mistake, I needed to change the address of the pointer pointing to the data, not the pointer pointing to the pointer. The new code is:

```
int pop(int **sp)
    {
            printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);
            num = (**sp);
            (*sp)--;
            printf("sp = %d\n",num);
            printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);

            return num;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `pop`, you are decrementing the value in stack rather than the pointer to it. Remember, `*sp` is the stack pointer, NOT `**sp`. So, you need to decrement `*sp` and not `**sp`.

```
int pop(int **sp)
{
    printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);
    /* num = (**sp)--; */  // ISSUE: Decrementing value instead of pointer
    num = *(*sp)--;
    printf("sp = %d\n",num);
    printf("sp for pop = %p\n", *sp);

    return num;
}
```

There is also an issue in `push` function. Althouh it does not create issue now, it is best to fix it.

```
void push(int num, int ** sp) 
{
    if (++(*sp) == NULL)
            printf("Stack Overflow");
    else{
            printf("sp for push = %p \n", *sp);
            // **sp++ = num;     // ISSUE: increment not needed.
                                 //        Once incremented, it will NOT point
                                 //        to stack pointer anymore 
            **sp = num;
    }
}
```

---

To check if you have space in the stack while pushing, and to check if any elements are there while popping, you can use an `index` variable to keep track of number of elements in stack.

Suppose Max capacity of stack is say `N`. Initialize the `index` to `0`.

Now whenever you push, first check if `index < N`, then only push ( and increment the `index` by `1`). If `index` is not smaller than `N`, then you have stackoverflow.

Whenever you pop, first check if `index > 0`, then only pop (and `decrement` the `index` by `1`). If `index` is not greater than `0`, then you  have no element to pop.

Also, worth mentionning, is that it is more natural if this `index` is named stack pointer - `sp` - which points to the top of stack. You can can pass the pointer to base of stack and call it `base` or something else. Your functions would then be:

```
void push(int num, int *base, int sp) { ... }  // base: start address of stack, 
int pop(int *base, int sp) { ... }             // sp:   index of top of stack
```